# Change the Conditionally formatted numbers into decimal(30,2) in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to change the (30,45,123.12) to -3045123.12 in SQL Server while before inserting in table? I am facing issue while converting the data.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Try_Convert(BIGINT, replace(nullif([numbersvalue], ''), ',', '')) IS NOT NULL
            THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, replace(nullif([numbersvalue], ''), ',', ''))
        ELSE 0
        END
FROM tables
```

Comment: Why wrap it in a `CASE` at all? Why not just `ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(bigint, REPLACE(NULLIF([numbersvalue], ''), ',', ''))),0)`? What's wrong with what you have, when it *appears* you already have a working solution

Comment: Numbers are numbers. They have no format. They are binary values. The only way you'd have a problem would be storing or passing numbers as text. The solution to that is to use the *correct* type - use `decimal(30,2)` as both the column *and* the query parameter type. Don't use string contatenation to create queries

Comment: no it gives me a value 0 instead of -3045123.12

Comment: BTW the format you posted is specific to *your* application only - the separators suggest India as the culture but using `()` for negatives is *not* used anywhere, except for business reports. You can't parse this even with `TRY_PARSE(numbersValue as decimal(30,2) USING `in-IN`)`

Comment: Because you cannot convert a **string** representation of a decimal value to `(big)int`. Integer values don't have decimal points. Like others have said, fix the data type, fix the problem.

Comment: @RamapriyanC fix the field type for starters. Use the correct type `decimal(30,2)`, and parse this *custom* format *before* entering the data into the database.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos im working in buisness report and i facing to inser those datas as a decimal for the negative value

Comment: If you used `-` for negative numbers you could use `select PARSE('-30,45,123.12' as decimal(30,2) USING 'in-IN')` to get `-3045123.12`. No culture uses parentheses for negative numbers though, that's styling applied to business reports. It's far easier to parse this format when *loading* the data using custom parsing in C# or VBScript (if you use SSIS), eg the [NumberStyles.AllowParentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.8) style in either C# or Java parses parentheses as negatives

Comment: So you're actually saying that negative values in are parenthesis and positive values aren't? I was simply under the assumption you wanted to remove all the commas and multiple by `-1`... 1 sample piece of data does not make us aware of all your scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try_convert(money, ... )`  It tends to be a little more forgiving

**Example**

```
Select try_convert(money,replace(replace('(30,45,123.12)','(','-'),')',''))
```

**Returns**

```
-3045123.12
```

Comment: will it cause any performance issue ,because it is having more than 5 million recons per transaction?

Comment: @RamapriyanC using the wrong type always causes performance issues. Worse, ti causes *correctness* issues if parsing produces an unexpected value. What if someone inserts data using a *non-Indian* format ? You'd get invalid indexing *and* invalid values

Comment: @RamapriyanC As Panagiotis mentioned, there are always penalties for storing numbers as strings.  Using MONEY requires only two replaces vs three.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti using `TRY_PARSE(... as decimal(30,2) USING 'in-IN')` also needs just two replacements, but that just hides the problem - non Indian values would result in NULLs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your full comment is now visible.  Yes, you are correct.  I tend to have the lazy American view.  I'll work in that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I use TRY_PARSE but note that it only works when converting to money:

```
    DECLARE @test varchar(255)
    SET @test = '(1.123,45)'
    SELECT TRY_PARSE(@test as money using 'de-DE')
    -- gives -1123.45

-- this won't work
    SELECT TRY_PARSE(@test as float using 'de-DE')
```

In my example the culture is German, which uses a comma as the decimal delimiter and a dot as the thousands separator.